# Where else do applications get the default browser from?

Tags: default-programs, default-browser

I have tried to set my default browser to a github installation of `qutebrowser`. For this purpose, I have a `/home/anaphory/.config/qutebrowser.desktop` file containing

```
[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.0
Name=Qutebrowser
GenericName=Web Browser
Comment=View and edit files
MimeType=text/html;
Exec=bash -c "source /home/anaphory/anaconda3/bin/activate qutebrowser; qutebrowser"
Icon=/home/anaphory/.config/qutebrowser.svg
Type=Application
Terminal=false
Categories=Network;Utility;X-Python;
StartupWMClass=Qutebrowser
X-Desktop-File-Install-Version=0.20
```

I have a script inside `/home/anaphory/anaconda3/bin`, which is part of $PATH due to `.profile`, also stating `source /home/anaphory/anaconda3/bin/activate qutebrowser; qutebrowser` – Both under `x-www-browser` and `gnome-www-browser`.

I have set `/home/anaphory/.config/qutebrowser.desktop` as default handler:

```
$ xdg-mime query default x-scheme-handler/https
/vol/home/kaipingga/.config/qutebrowser.desktop
```

(also for `text/html` and `x-scheme-handler/http`). 
The `.desktop` works from my applications starter bar, and `x-www-browser` and `gnome-www-browser` start qutebrowser from the terminal.

Still, `xdg-open http://askubuntu.com`, clicking a link in `emacs`, etc. opens it in Firefox, and “Run” (Alt+F2) `x-www-browser` runs Firefox.

My settings→Default Applications are still set to *Firefox*, because that drop-down list only shows Firefox and Chromium. I don't have root permissions.

Answer (score 0):

Can you select it in the default application list if you put your desktop file in `~/.local/share/applications` instead?

Also, some applications also use the `$BROWSER` environment variable.